# How to have each item in my UITableViewController push to an individual UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am trying to set up a UITableViewController where each item in the TableView will push to an individual ViewController. I created an array

```
NSArray *cities=@["NewYork", @"Chicago", @"LosAngeles", @"Miami"];
```

and implemented it into my UITableViewController. Then I pushed to a new UIViewController;

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:NewYorkViewController animated:YES];
```

However now all the items in the array/tableview push to "NewYorkViewController". How do I have each city in the array/table view push to their own ViewController?

I have created a UIViewController for each individual city e.g. "ChicagoViewController" etc.
and I don't use storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to use an `NSDictionary` and map your cities string to each `UIViewController` class. Then you just use `objectForKey` and get the correct view controller for each key.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing that? Pushing to a separate `viewController` is waste of time. Just make a `detailViewController` and push the data from one to another. In you code you can do whatever you want to that `viewController`. Because of pushed data you can decide which `tab` is pressed. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate your four view controllers and add them  to an NSArray:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = @[NewYorkViewController, ChicagoViewController, 
                             LosAngelesViewController, MiamiViewController];
```

Then in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: you can push the corresponding view controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllers[indexPath.row] animated:YES];
```

Comment: but then it doesn't have any text in my UITableViewController. The point of having the strings was that it displayed text for the tableview

Comment: @rivtracks -- use the `viewControllers` array in **addition** to the `cities` array.

Comment: an array of strings and an array of objects, sounds awful a lot like an NSDictionary no? i think enrico's solution is a better fit

Comment: besides nsdictionary how would I implement both arrays because when I do self.viewcontrollers=@[NewYorkViewController, ChicagoViewController, LosAngelesViewController, MiamiViewController]; self.cities=@[@"New York", @"Chicago", @"Los Angeles", @"Miami"]; and then in //numberOfRowsInSection: return self.cities.count and then in didselectrowatIndexPath: [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewControllers animated:YES]; it doesnt seem to work. What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

First let me start by saying the best option will be to have your array of city names and then instantiate the correct view controller in your row selection method.  But if I can't dissuade you, here a more complicated option:

Instead of storing a name in your array, store an array of dictionaries:

```
NSArray *cities=@[@{@"city":@"NewYork",@"viewController":NewYorkViewController}, @{@"city":@"Chicago",@"viewController":ChicagoViewController}, @{@"city":@"LosAngeles",@"viewController":LosAngelesViewController}, @{@"city":@"Miami",@"viewController":MiamiViewController}];
```

When getting a city name in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: get the city out like this:

```
NSString *cityName = [[cities objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] objectForName:@"city"];
```

Then when you respond to the selection of a row get the view controller:

```
UIViewController *cityViewController = [[cities objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] objectForName:@"viewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cityViewController animated:yes];
```

Assuming all the city view controllers are instantiated, that should work.

Comment: would you be able to show and explain the "best option" in your opinion? thanks

Comment: At some point you're instantiating the view controllers.  Just don't do that until you make your selection and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: runs.  You're already doing what needs to be done, you're just doing it in the wrong place.